# Amazon S3 storage of sensitive files

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download

I am looking to set up a download space on s3.

I am sending an email to an authorised user to my site so that they can click a link and download a File.

I would like to keep this file hidden from public view altogether, but if I do this how exactly will I be able to assign/'tag' a file with a particular user on my website database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [AWS S3 Share an Object with Others](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html):

> All objects by default are private. Only the object owner has
>   permission to access these objects. However, the object owner can
>   optionally share objects with others by creating a pre-signed URL,
>   using their own security credentials, to grant time-limited permission
>   to download the objects.

For each object you want to share, you will need to generate a pre-signed URL, with an expiration period.  This URL can then be sent to a user.  This is an example of the [how to generate a pre-signed URL using PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-url.html):

```
$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => 'my-bucket',
    'Key'    => 'testKey'
]);

$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');

// Get the actual presigned-url
$presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
```

> how exactly will I be able to assign/'tag' a file with a particular
>   user on my website database?

If you want to track which files have been granted access to a particular user, you could create a table that stores the userId, the bucket/key, the pre-signed URL, and an expirationDate.  This would allow you and/or the user to reference the URL later.  The files could be aged from the table based on the expirationDate.